# JOOQ how to ignore unmapped fields of result record set

Tags: java, jooq

I want to calcualte Pagination Metadata Without Extra Roundtrips

```
dslContext.selectDistinct(count().over().as("total"),
                ID,NAME
            .from(TABLE)
.fetchGroups(field("total", Integer.class), MyProjection.class);
```

During runtime I get next exception :

> org.jooq.exception.MappingException: 
>  No DefaultRecordMapper
> strategy applies to type class MyProjection for row type
> "total","id","name" .

I dont want to add total field in MyProjection.class .
What is most simple way to resolve this issue ?

MyProjection java class body :

```
import java.util.UUID;

public record MyProjection(
        UUID id,
        String name
) {
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `MyProjection` class here? Please be careful to make sure your probably simplified example represents the actual example, i.e. that the example helps reproduce the problem. E.g. you'll have to include all constructors, properties, etc.

Answer (score 1):

#### How the reflective `DefaultRecordMapper` works

When you use reflection to map data into your objects ("POJOs", "DTOs"), then the mapping rules are specified by [`DefaultRecordMapper`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/dev/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DefaultRecordMapper.html). In particular:

> If no default constructor is available, but at least one "matching" constructor is available, that one is used
>
> [...]
>
> If no default constructor is available, no "matching" constructor is available, but [`Settings.isMapConstructorParameterNames()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/dev/org.jooq/org/jooq/conf/Settings.html#isMapConstructorParameterNames()) is turned on, and parameter names are available through reflection on [`Executable.getParameters()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Executable.html#getParameters()), the first constructor is used

Key here is the understanding of the word *"matching"*, which, by default, means matching by arity. If you project 3 columns, jOOQ by default will look only for 3-parameter constructors. This works in the same way as a lot of SQL operators, including `UNION` or `ROW` comparisons, where column names are irrelevant, and only column ordinals matter.

If there are only 2-parameter constructors for a 3-column row, jOOQ can't just assume that you omitted a parameter only for a given argument. Which one would you have omitted? The first, second, or third?

You could try making a case in favour of being lenient here, but it would be *very* confusing to get this consistent with the rest of the [`DefaultRecordMapper`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/dev/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DefaultRecordMapper.html) specification, as well as with future potential features, so jOOQ just won't do it.

However, a `record` formally exposes its canonical constructor's parameter names, so if you do turn on [`Settings.isMapConstructorParameterNames()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/dev/org.jooq/org/jooq/conf/Settings.html#isMapConstructorParameterNames()), then your expectations will be met, even if you re-order your arguments, as long as you make sure they're named `id` and `name`. Do note that this flag will apply to *all* mappings with access to your `Settings`, so that will be quite the change for any other mappings, including ones that map by index but potentially mis-name a SQL column! Note, only `record` types expose their parameter names in Java, not ordinary constructors (by default), so this flag will only work for records.

If you use a mutable POJO with only a default constructor, however, then fields are again mapped by name (which is the only sensible option, in that case).

#### Alternatives using custom `RecordMapper`

Just because there's a `DefaultRecordMapper` doesn't mean you have to use it for everything mapping related. You have quite a specific use-case, which you probably re-use quite often in your application, so why not provide jOOQ with an extension via the `RecordMapperProvider` SPI? An example is here:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/pojos-with-recordmapper-provider/

*You* know that you'll always call your field `total`, so you know how to exclude it from all mappings.